# Comparing an int value with APInt Clang ASTVisitors

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, semantics, visitor-pattern

I'd like to compare the bound of an `ImplicCastExpr` in my ASTvisitor check, but it seems `Clang` wouldn't allow me to do that:

```
static bool vectorLoopConditionVisitor(Sema &S, Expr *E){

    if(!E){
      S.Diag(E->getBeginLoc(), diag::err_...);
    } else{ 
        const BinaryOperator *BO = dyn_cast<BinaryOperator>(E);
          if(!BO) {
            if(const IntegerLiteral *IL = dyn_cast_or_null<IntegerLiteral>(BO->getRHS()->IgnoreParenImpCasts())) {
              if( IL->getValue() > 65535){
                S.Diag(BO->getOperatorLoc(), diag::err_...);
              }
return false;
}
```

This will throw the following error as I am trying to compare an `int` value with an `llvm::APInt`:

```
invalid operands to binary expression ('llvm::APInt' and 'int')
```

However, I  did a similar comparison without any issue in my other function:

```
static bool vectorLoopInitializationsVisitor(Sema &S, Stmt *St) {


  DeclStmt *Dst = dyn_cast<DeclStmt>(St);


  if (!Dst->isSingleDecl()) {
  ¦ S.Diag(St->getBeginLoc(), diag::err_...);
  }
  VarDecl const *VD = dyn_cast<VarDecl>(Dst->getSingleDecl());

  if(const IntegerLiteral *IL = dyn_cast<IntegerLiteral>(VD->getInit()->IgnoreImpCasts())){
    if (IL->getValue() != 0) {
  ¦   if (IL->getValue() !=
  ¦ ¦   ¦ 12345) { 
  ¦ ¦   S.Diag(St->getBeginLoc(), diag::err_...);
  ¦   }
    }
return false;
}
```

Checking both types, there are of `llvm::APInt` and `int`. Can anyone explain why is that?

In other words, what does CompoundOperator `!=` do which BinaryOperator `>` doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

llvm::APInt represents a fixed-width bit vector. It doesn't distinguish between signed and unsigned values, so you can't simply use >, >=, <, and <= to compare values because it doesn't know whether you want to interpret the value of the APInt as a signed or unsigned number. != and == work because they have the same semantics for both signed and unsigned quantities.

As you can see [here](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1IntegerLiteral.html), llvm::APInt provides separate signed and unsigned greater-than comparisons using the sgt and ugt methods. These methods provide overloads that take a a int64_t and a uint64_t respectively.

Thus, the correct code would be either: `if( IL->getValue().ugt(65535)` or `if( IL->getValue().sgt(65535))`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarifications. I was trying to cast it to `llvm::ConstantInt` for comparisons, but your answer is robust.